# How to launch PreferenceScreen from the parent one

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

I've added in my app a simple AlertDialog that asks if the user wants to be redirected to the info PreferenceScreen. I'd like to know how to launch a child PreferenceScreen from the parent one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "info" PreferenceScreen, but when writing the preference xml file that you load in your `PreferenceActivity` subclass you can nest the `PreferenceScreen` tags:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orderingFromXml="true" >
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:title="Child preference screen"
        android:summary="Description">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="check1"
            android:title="Checkbox"
            android:summaryOff="off"
            android:summaryOn="on" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The child preference screen will be show automatically when touching the entry in the parent preference screeen.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to redirect the user to another PreferenceScreen automatically, without touching the entry. Thanks.

Comment: You could put your "info" `PreferenceScreen` into a new resource and subclass a new `PreferenceActivity` for it. Then, on button click, start that activity. Also, add an `OnPreferenceClickListener` in which you start the activity

Answer (score 0):

I've provided [my solution](/questions/5213047/how-to-navigate-to-nested-preferencesscreen/5263917#5263917) for the similar question.